# onActivityResult() method called too early for starting call activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to start a phone call from my application and when user end the call it will show a message to the user. I am using this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + rowItem.getMobileNumber()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CALL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But when this activity is called and at the same time onActivityResult() is called. But I want to get it after user end the call. How can I solve the problem.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_CALL doesn't work that way. I suppose you are trying to get some data from dialer or call?

Comment: Is there any way to do that @RohanKandwal

Comment: first tell me what you actually want?

Comment: I have a custom listview. Each list item has call icon. Each user can click on call icon and after the end of this call I want to show a message to the user. @RohanKandwal

Comment: How can I solve the issu @RohanKandwal

Comment: what kind of a message?

Comment: The Activity you start has to send some data back so you can read in startActivityForResult but in your case you don't control Call Intent. You could use onResume function of Activity to show some message on return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intent.ACTION_CALL` doesn't return anything for `startActivityForResult()` won't do anything. Make your code such that when user press `listview`, the number is directly called, then even if user disconnect the call, a call is already being made. So you can directly add the number in your `listview`.

Comment: If I create BroadcastReceiver, then it may show message for all calls. I just want to show it only for my application @RohanKandwal

Comment: It will do what you want. Above piece of code will return the number called but why don't you just add the number on activity `onResume` i.e. after the call is disconnected? Just make sure that you make direct call not just showing number on dialer.

Comment: what i meant is that make your code such that when user press listview, the number is directly called, then even if user disconnect the call, a call is already being made. So you can directly add the number in your listview without any broadcastRecievers and all.